# Parse iOS SDK: How to copy objectId while creating a PFObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Scenario = I have a PFQueryTableViewController that will display messages that users send to each other. To create a relationship between the conversations, I saved a string to the object called "messageID". I want "messageID" to be an exact copy of the **first** message's "objectId" in order for the conversation to make chronological sense and I will 'orderByAscending' from the "createdAt" perimeter.

Question = How do I set (copy) the "objectId" from the first message?

The idea I am trying to do is this...

```
PFObject *message = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Message"];
[message setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.messageTextView.text] forKey:@"message"];
[message setObject:[PFUser currentUser][@"userID"] forKey:@"senderID"];
[message setObject:self.selectedFriendID forKey:@"receiverID"];

//RIGHT HERE
[message setObject:message.objectId forKey:@"messageID"];

[message saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

}
```

The idea is this way all of the messages once queried in the PFQueryTableViewController will all belong together and in order because they all have the same "messageID".

This gives me an error 'Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values.'

If anyone could point me in the right direction so I can accomplish this I will love you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message tells you what is happening - you are trying to store a nil value in the `messageID` key, which isn't permitted.

The reason it is happening is the `objectId` is only assigned once the object is saved - a newly allocated object doesn't have a value yet.

So, you can either wait until the `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` has completed and retrieve the objectId then or you can use an alternative ID.

I would suggest you change your `messageID` column to a String and use a UUID.  You can then create a new UUID before you save the first message in the conversation.  You can use

```
NSString *messageID=[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
```

Comment: Wow I had no idea of this class. VERY useful class for this case. And you provided two useful answers that both work and did it to the point. Very good answer. Thanks Paul.